# Why isn't the score updating on my scoreboard?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need help with why my score is not updating when the Python turtle collides with the food.  I have also posted a link below with the complete code:

```
if turtle.distance(food) < 20:
            food.goto(randint(-280, 280), randint(-280, 280))
            # Adding sections
            new_section = Turtle()# Turtle() is the same as turtle.Turtle()
            new_section.shape('square')
            new_section.speed(0)
            new_section.color('orange', 'grey')
            new_section.penup()
            new_section.goto(old_position)
            sections.append(new_section)# Adds new section of body at the end of body

            # Score
            score = 0
            high_score = 0

            # Increase the score
            score = + 10


            if score > high_score:
                high_score = score
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("Score: {} High Score: {}".format(score, high_score), align="center",font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

***Need help on updating score have also posted link below***


    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move, DELAY)
```

[pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/VgTvH6vp) for full code.

Comment: Its hard to have a sense of what your code is trying to do and where your error is. Perhaps you could try to isolate the code to the relevant parts and post the error and provide a more detailed context? For example, provide the sample input and expected output as well.

Comment: You are correct I apologize I am kinda new to using stack overflow I have edited it and I hope it is much clearer to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `score` and `highscore` are local to `move()` and are reset to zero anew each time it runs.  They need to be global, and declared `global`.

If we look at `move()` from a *score* perspective, it looks like:

```
def move():
    score = 0
    high_score = 0
    # Increase the score
    score = + 10
    if score > high_score:
        high_score = score
    pen.write("Score: {} High Score: {}".format(score, high_score), ...))
```

Where `score` and `highscore` are *local* to `move()`.  What we really expect is more like:

```
score = 0
high_score = 0

def move():
    global score, high_score

    # Increase the score
    score += 10
    if score > high_score:
        high_score = score
    pen.write("Score: {} High Score: {}".format(score, high_score), ...))
```

Read about the Python `global` keyword, and about Python global variables in general.

Comment: Can you go a little more in depth on what you mean?

Comment: @Ralph9496, I've augmented my answer accordingly.  You appear to be programming beyond your understanding of the language -- take a break from coding to read about the features being discussed above.

Comment: Truly though thanks again for the help @cdlane really appreciate every tip you provide hope to be at your level someday.

Comment: @Ralph9496 functions `def` are by default `local` in their scope. This is to ensure that functions are pure and do not affect outside of their own scope. Using `globals` is 1 way around this but it is far safer to pass in variables directly via `def move(var1, var2, var3)` and do a `return (output1, output2)` to pass computed variables outside of the function's scope. This will also make debugging easier should your code size get bigger.

Comment: @ycx, if you examine the context, `move()` is an event handler for `ontimer()` so passing in arguments would require a `lambda` or a `partial()` call.  And there's no simple way to get at any returned values.  Although well meaning, I believe your advice would break the OP's code.